# Using dynamic css in angular6 components

Tags: css, angular, components, modularity

I'm using two different components A: sea.component.ts  and B:sun.component.ts both call a child component in these child I have to load a different css if is called by sea or sun component. Is possible to pass css url as an input in child component  as:

```
 <sun_parent>
     <child [css]="sun_css"></child>
 </parent>

 <sea_parent>
     <child [css]="sun_css"></child>
 </sea_parent>
```

Comment: Yes. You can create an object to pass as an input, as use the object with `ngStyle` https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 1):

There could be a way maybe but here's a suggestion: Both of your component calls the same child component, so you can take advantage of it by using an id on the parent div, like this:

Here's an example:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/reuseable-component

```
<parent id="iAmSeaParent">
    <child></child>
</parent>

<parent id="iAmSunParent">
    <child></child>
</parent>
```

**In your style.css**

```
#iAmSeaParent childClassOrIdOrTag {
    background: yellow;
}

#iAmSunParent childClassOrIdOrTag {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this wouldn't work because of view encapsulation

Comment: Isn't he looking for something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2m7mk 

or I didn't understand anything?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were adding it to `style.css` (which doesn't feature ViewEncapsulation) as opposed to the component's own CSS file

Comment: NP. This is why I made a stackbliz demo... because if the answer's not correct then it shouldn't be here and I would have deleted it.